# xhtml in old browsers

Tags: html, xhtml

Consider the following xhtml:

```
<img src="myImage.jpg" alt="My image" />
<br />
<hr />
```

I wonder, if this code would work correctly in old browsers, that have no xhtml support, but only html. I'd test it by myself, but I haven't any old enough browser on my PC. Links to the documentation will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work fine in older browsers.

XHTML was specifically formulated to work with browsers that support HTML 4.

You can read up on the w3 backwards compatibility guidelines for XHTML 1.0 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines).